# redirect non existence url to folder

Tags: .htaccess

1. i am a user, and i type: www.japsomething.com, that url doesn't exist however there is a folder called "something" and i want this url to point to that folder?

do i need to purchase the domain name for this to work or i can use .htaccess?

i still would like to preserve the url. so this means, even though i am coming from 
www.japsomething.com the url should still say www.japsomething.com and when i click anything on the site it should say www.japsomething.com/anything/

1. another question is, how can i detect based on the users ip that i want to show them a spanish site, or an english site?

thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

> do i need to purchase the domain name for this to work or i can use .htaccess?

You need to purchase the domain name, because otherwise when someone types: www.japsomething.com, their DNS is going to try to look that name up, and if you don't own that domain, the request is never going to reach your server, thus, your htaccess file is never even used. Because you don't own every domain that starts with "jap" and ends with ".com", you can't use htaccess to do this.

> i still would like to preserve the url. so this means, even though i am coming from www.japsomething.com the url should still say www.japsomething.com and when i click anything on the site it should say www.japsomething.com/anything/

If you own the "japsomething.com" domain, you simply point it to the server and directory that contains all the content, and then be done with it. No htaccess trickery is involved here. If you went out and bought the "japsomethingelse.com" domain, simply point it to the directory that serves that.

> another question is, how can i detect based on the users ip that i want to show them a spanish site, or an english site?

See [mod_geoip2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/) for downloads and examples.